# Media files wont show up with nginx, but static files will

Tags: python, django, nginx, media, digital-ocean

I have a problem with configuring my nginx. My media files are not showing up.
settings.py:
[image: screenshot 1]

nginx site config file:
[image: screenshot 2]

website:
[image: screenshot 3]

a part of nginx/error.log:

```
2019/08/25 20:28:10 [error] 28230#28230: *1 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184012.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184012.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:28:10 [error] 28230#28230: *4 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184214.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184214.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:28:10 [error] 28230#28230: *5 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184328.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184328.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:28:20 [error] 28230#28230: *5 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184328.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184328.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/admin/web_data/photo_gallery/2/change/"
2019/08/25 20:31:39 [error] 28230#28230: *13 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184328.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184328.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/admin/web_data/photo_gallery/2/change/"
2019/08/25 20:41:29 [error] 28230#28230: *14 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184012.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184012.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:41:29 [error] 28230#28230: *18 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184328.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184328.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:41:29 [error] 28230#28230: *19 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184214.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184214.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:44:54 [error] 28571#28571: *1 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184012.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184012.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:44:54 [error] 28571#28571: *2 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184214.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184214.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:44:54 [error] 28571#28571: *5 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184328.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184328.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:46:40 [error] 28571#28571: *6 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184328.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184328.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/admin/web_data/photo_gallery/2/change/"
2019/08/25 20:52:51 [error] 28571#28571: *17 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184328.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184328.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/admin/web_data/photo_gallery/2/change/"
2019/08/25 20:57:43 [error] 28571#28571: *21 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184328.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184328.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:57:43 [error] 28571#28571: *23 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184012.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184012.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
2019/08/25 20:57:43 [error] 28571#28571: *24 open() "/home/admin_aljaz/patricija_website/media/image/20190816_184214.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 78.153.61.113, server: 104.248.83.156, request: "GET /media/image/20190816_184214.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "104.248.83.156", referrer: "http://104.248.83.156/"
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code, include it in your question as text

Comment: what is the url requested by the browser for the image?

Comment: url requested by the browser for the image: http://104.248.83.156/media/image/20190816_184012.jpg

Comment: Thats the website: http://104.248.83.156/

Comment: check the folder and file permission of media

Comment: ![valid XHTML](http://shrani.si/f/3a/84/vhBNyI3/capture.jpg) here is the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it... 
The problem was in:
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
the default is :
(at the top of the file)
user www-data;
and then i changed it to:
user admin_aljaz;
And everything started to work :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Centos 7, try [disabling SELinux](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/) using:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

Comment: i'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: can you try changing the 'root' in location /media/ to 'alias' and restart nginx?